# Turning data inside a string into numbers in php

Tags: php, decode, encode, string-conversion

I'm currently working with data I'd like to temporarily store in my database as encrypted data. I'm not worried about the database getting hacked into, I just want to ensure the people that had entered the data that it is not reachable by any other than themselves. (and me of course)

The data is not meant to be stored permanently in the database since I'm exporting it to a third party application using their API, but since they have a rate limit I need to store the data in our database until the limit is over and I can upload it. (Assuming the rate limit occurs)

The process:

The request I receive from the form is in an array, so to begin with I serialize() the array to get a long string which I will unserialize() later.
Then I want to use a method that lets me convert the string into numbers and back again without losing information.

The reason I want to turn the data into numbers is because I use the HashIds library, which only encodes numbers. To my knowledge it's an extra layer of security I'm happy to add.

Read more on HashIds here: http://hashids.org/

What I have tried:

- I tried converting the string into hex numbers, and then the hex numbers into decimals. Unfortunately the number was too large, and i haven't had any luck using biginteger with it.
- base64_encode() which is not going to turn the data into numbers, but then base_converting them is. But I couldn't figure out the base converting in php since apparently it's rather odd.

Conclusion:

How can I convert the data I'm receiving from a form request into a short encoded string which can be converted back into the data without too much hassle? I don't quite know all the options PHP offers yet.

**UPDATE:**

To conclude this thread, I ended up using OpenSSL to encrypt my serialized array. Only problem I ran into was if the request contained a file I wouldn't be able to serialize it and save the object to the database. I do still need a way around this, since the third party application expects the file to be a multipart/formdata object i can't just save the filepath to the database and upload that. But I guess I will have to figure out that one later.

Answer (score 0):

That link http://hashids.org/ provides a pretty clear example. Lets assume that your integer is `15`.

```
$hashids = new Hashids\Hashids('some random string for a salt. Make sure you use the same salt if you want to be able to decode');

$encoded = $hashids->encode(15);
print_r(['hashedId' => $encoded]);

$decoded = $hashids->decode($hashed);
print_r(['decoded' => $decoded]);
```

So the value of `$decoded` should equal 15

**Update**

Sorry - the `hashids` bit of your question threw me and as such, I misunderstood what you were asking. I will update my answer:

You should really be using https://secure.php.net/openssl_encrypt and https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-decrypt.php

Comment: The OP is trying to convert a string, such as `"Some super secret data here"` into an integer, so he can encrypt it with hashids. Obviously this is a bizarre thing to do, and hashids is clearly not the tool for the job, but regardless, this is not an answer to the OPs question

Comment: Hey @Steve is there a better way you would recommend ? Because i'm open to suggestions, this was just the first thing that came in mind because i already use the HashIds for other reasons in the project :)

Comment: @Kjaal Encryption is hard. If the key is saved in the same place as the data, it doesnt adda whole lot of security. I know enough to tell you its hard, but not enough to give you a solution.However if you are just looking to be able to say in good faith `"All data entered into the form is encrypted"` then you can just use `openssl_encrypt() / openssl_decrypt()` on the user input